# dynamic constructor injection in spring

Tags: java, spring

I am learning Spring Core. I am facing some problem.

As in constructor injection, values are passed through xml file which contains bean definition.

I want to define the bean in xml file and want to initialized the bean with dynamic value passed by the user. Is it possible to create bean with dynamic value by using constructor injection ? What are the various ways to do this?

Comment: dynamic? like from a properties file?

Comment: dynamic means by passing values provided by user.

Comment: Can you be more specific on how the user provides the values? From console?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

You would have to refactor and inject a provider/factory of your required class, ie add a level of abstraction. You can then call this provider/factory with your required values and get an appropriate instance.